# Absorption of Diazepam/Valium

Tags: drugs, pharmacology

Why diazepam absorbs quickly when taken with metoclopramide? Does it because diazepam is absorbed from intestine like acetaminophen? If it does, why presence of food increases the absorption of diazepam. Meals can slow down gastric emptying and delay diazepam reaching small intestine. So if diazepam is absorbed from intestine, presence of food tends to slow down diazepam absorption, correct?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here.  I think this is better suited for [Biology.SE], but I fear they will close it as being too broad.  A more general question about absorption might be a better route to go initially.